# C# Builder Class in Quasar Open source

Tags: c#, server, client, quasar

I'm trying to get into understanding quasar source code (R.A.T) [on Github](https://github.com/quasar/QuasarRAT)

It's an Advanced Communication between Server/Client using Commands.

The interesting part which I didn't really understand is the `Class Builder` which uses The Mono.cecil Reference to modify Assembly Variables's values that they were Empty such as Host, Port etc...

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: @mmcrae An Explication on how it works i almost understand the class code but how  the class use The `Client.bin` and create a new executable

Comment: it would probably help if you shrank down the code a whole lot and focused on the specific thing with `Client.bin` that seems odd

Comment: @mmcrae its what i did but it doesnt seems to find any definition for `AssemblyDefinition` on the Mono.Cecil Dll , a quick notice is there is a post build in the project `copy "$(TargetPath)" "$(TargetDir)client.bin" /Y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by asking the project owner about the Client.bin file and was about the Mono.cecil reference [can be found here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/)

and i got some examples on how to use there